how to make authentication with breeze based on Role .and use spatie for handling permissions
i want to make authentication with laravel base on role ; superAdmin, admin,user,
for that i want many to many relationships between user model and Role model which will result a pivot table role_user.
the second step is i want to use spatie for handling permissions for each role.
the chanllenge is spatie comes with role and role_user.so so when creating those for autentication is it possible that they  will be confused?
can anyone help me with please ?
suggest a solution,a step by step guide
